# Chrome Table Overflows With Odd URL

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css, google-chrome

So I posted this before, but maybe I didn't have enough information. I'm having issues with Chrome and how it has a hard time wrapping long URLs in a table cell. Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/qqsj8/ . I have seen a lot of questions regarding word wrapping and some even had with long URLs but none of them worked for me. So essentially, I tried putting in the td

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

but this doesn't wrap the long URL which is (changed here, doesn't go to anything):

```
https://differentName/api/?REQUEST=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%271.0%27%20%3F%3E%3Cnta%3E%3Capi%20version%3D%271.0%27%3E%woot%20function%3D%22login%22%3E%3Clogin%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5Bjpublic%something.com%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Flogin%3E%3Cpassword%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5Bnta46550%5D%5D%3E%3C%2F
```

I've tried adding a width property onto the td but I get nothing. I was also told that when using the word-wrap property to also include:

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

But I don't want my columns fixed in width. Also, I don't have the wrapping issue if I use the fixed property. I'm working off of the latest version of Chrome (as of this date). No issues with FF 26.0 or IE 11. Also, its important to note that I have temp fix styling the cell like:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

This isn't the solution I'm looking for. The cell isn't a static cell. I am using ASP.NET (VB.NET) to pull the values needed (from a DB) to populate these cells. So although that solution works for this specific case, it would be applied to all information in the description section for other records. So as a permanent solution, that break-all styling won't work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use word-break: break-word? Under what case would this not be a good solution?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qqsj8/4/  added  `max-width:100px;word-wrap:break-word;`

Comment: omg, how did this not work for me? I could of swore I tried that... I guess I'm just going crazy or something. Thank you @KJ Price, I'm good now. Really appreciate it. Put the answer in and I'll mark this question as solved. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
word-break: break-word
```

That should do it.